# No compila correctamente-angular (no hay errores)

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, angular, web

Me arroja esto en la consola de *Chrome* y no tengo idea.

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
> core.js:40658

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Hola! Eso no parece tener que ver con Angular. Por qué crees que hay un error de compilación? Parece más bien un error en el navegador, asociado a una extensión...

Comment: el código de extensión sugiere que es adblock https://www.google.com/search?q=extension%3A%2F%2Fgighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente esas advertencias son de alguna extensión, tal y como lo dijo nat en su comentario. En mi caso era un adBlock , al eliminar la extensión dejaron de aparecer esos problemas. Probablemente el adBlock detecta que algunos recursos de tu app podrían ser tomados parcialmente como anuncios o dentro del código de AdBlock tiene presente el bloquear recursos de cierto tipo, y pueda que esto haga crashear o no abrir tu app del todo.